# Put good GRE scores on resume submitted with grad app?

Tags: graduate-admissions, gre

If you have good GRE scores, is it a good idea to put them on the resume that you submit with your grad school application?

Answer (score 1):

You typically have ETS send the school your official GRE scores anyway so this information is going to be redundant.

It shouldn't bother most people if it is on there but I don't see it helping you really either. I would only do it if I have some space needing to be filled on my resume and my scores were really high.

Answer (score 1):

As said above, I would leave them off. Keep the resume for university and experience you've had.